# CMS or Re-Uploading pages

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system

I have a site I'm working on that has an event page.  The owner wants to be able to edit the event page weekly.  Would it be easier to teach the site owner how to edit this one page and upload it or use a CMS just for this one page??

Apart from a contact form that posts to an email addy, the rest of the site is static.  Therefore I'd need to add in a db to store the username and password for CMS login.

If CMS then which one would be most suitable for this case?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complexity of the page. If it's a fixed structure where the client won't want to add links of photos you may want to give them the ability to edit a simple data file (not the page itself). Then read in the data file. I like to use a simple JSON format for this type of thing.

At least with a data file you can revert to an older version or handle the error gracefully, rather than having the client break the whole page.

If you want to go the CMS route, [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) has a very well-established comunity with plenty of add-ons.

If you're more into roll-your-own programming, you can also look at the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/),

Comment: The idea of a simple data file sounds quite suitable.  Would you have the user upload the file to the server directly or provide a login page on the website the allows them to upload the file that way ? ?

Comment: Either through a form file upload or FTP. The form is better because you can trigger the program to test and parse the file immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not want to deal with software installation & database setup to edit a single page.

You might consider an FTP-based CMS.  This would give you access to a nice web-based WYSIWYG editor and any changes you make would be transferred via FTP to your web host.

Here are a couple of services that do this:

CushyCMS - http://www.cushycms.com/

nextEdit - http://www.nextedit.net/

In this scenario no software installation or databases would be required.

**Update:** One more service is TypeRoom - http://www.typeroom.com/  I had forgotten about this one.  I tested it a few months back and was impressed.